# Do 301 redirects in .htaccess need to be in a priority order?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site which has been redeveloped and the URLs are totally different. I've hundreds or 301 to do (the original URLs many were very long - I have no idea why) and I'm getting some funny results where some redirects are happening and others are redirecting, but to odd URLs. I was wondering if there is a specific order 301's need to go in. For example:

```
redirect 301 /News/Smart-Site-Waste-Management.aspx http://...
redirect 301 /News/tabid/96/tagid/68/damaged-doors.aspx http://...
redirect 301 /News/tabid/96/EntryId/91/Smart-Site-Waste-Management.aspx http://...
redirect 301 /News/tabid/96/EntryId/156/Plastic-Surgeon-hits-the-headlines.aspx http://...
redirect 301 /News/RepairoftheWeek/tabid/194/tagid/78/Gallery/RepairoftheWeek/tabid/194/EntryId/221/Scratched-laminate-floor-repair.aspx http://...
```

So my actual question is, should the "smaller" urls (the ones with less directory levels) be lower down this order and the more specific URLs be higher? My instinct tells me that if it's set as above, all those URLs will direct to the new link specified in the FIRST as they all start with "News/". This is what I am seeing in practice.

Answer (score 5):

You need to place the most specific at the top and the least specific at the bottom. Also, make sure you're halting processing using [L] after each redirect rule to make sure apache doesn't process additional rewrite rules after it has found a rule that matches.

Could you please post your .htaccess file?

Comment: Great stuff - thanks very much for your answer. I had not realised I needed the [L] after each rule which makes perfect sense. You may have realised I'm pretty new to complex .htaccess writing.

Answer (score 0):

Order is only important if there are multiple match lines (e.g. if you are also using `RedirectMatch` or the mod_rewrite `RewriteEngine On` which can interact with redirect directives.

You will experience a performance hit parsing 100s of rule in an htaccess file, especially if the match rate is now small.  If your current URIs do not start with /News, then a good trick is to move all of these redirects to `DOCROOT/News/.htaccess` as this will only be parsed for URIs /News/.... and hence out of any other URI path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As the folders themselves do not exist on the new server I guess I'd need to actually create them then add the .htaccess for each.

Comment: You can simply create a stub News directory with the .htaccess in it.  What this means is that the 90+% of requests which do not include the /News/ path in their URI don't have the hits of the rewrite engine scanning these 100s of rewrite rules