# 301 Redirect won't work

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

I've redesigned a website (former windows/asp) and the new website runs on wordpress.

So I wanted to do 301 Redirects on all old links, but somehow this isn't working and I'm new to .htaccess redirects.

```
Redirect 301 /index.asp http://balbla.com/#work    
Redirect 301 /index.asp?ID=177 http://blabla.com/portfolio/blablatitle/
```

It seems all behind "?" gets ignored. Because `blabla.com/index.asp?ID=177` redirects now to `http://balbla.com/#work?ID=177`

Can anyone help me?

---

So these are the different pattern types of the urls, each of them should redirect to a different page:

Mainpages:

```
/index.asp?inc=index.asp&typ=Nav1&cat=2
/index.asp?inc=index.asp&typ=Nav1&cat=3
...
```

Portfolio-Pages:

```
/?inc=index.asp&ID=5
/?inc=index.asp&ID=24
/?inc=index.asp&ID=147
```

Subpages:

```
/index.asp?inc=agentur/advertising.asp
/index.asp?inc=agentur/design.asp
/index.asp?inc=agentur/dialog.asp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537636/do-301-redirects-in-htaccess-need-to-be-in-a-priority-order

Comment: Probably this question helps you out:
[.htaccess 301 redirect not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132467/htaccess-301-redirect-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Should each "pattern type" redirect to a different URL, or literally every URL should redirect to a different URL. Is there any relationship between the source and target URLs?

Comment: every url should redirect to a different url ;)
Yes there is a realtionship between source and target. 
The source is the old website (on windowsserver with asp.net) and the target is the redesigned website (on apache / wordpress).

Comment: By "relationship", I mean a relationship in the URL pattern. eg. `/index.asp?inc=index.asp&typ=<nav>&cat=<cat>` might map to `/portfolio/<nav>/<cat>`? If not then you are likely to have to do every redirect separately. In which case .htaccess might not be the best approach. If the old URLs don't exist on the new website then consider using a cutsom 404 and storing these URLs in a lookup table or database (if there are many). If you have access to the server config then using a `RewriteMap` might also be a possibility.

Comment: sorry got this wrong. no there is no relationship in the pattern :P
If I want to do this in the .htaccess I have to do this for each url am I wright? 

mainpages:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =inc=index.asp&typ=Nav1&cat=2`
`RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ http://domain.com/mainpage1/ [R=301,L]`
portfolio-pages:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =inc=index.asp&ID=5`
`RewriteRule ^/$ http://domain.com/portfolio/portfolioitem [R=301,L]`
subpages:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =inc=agentur/advertising.asp`
`RewriteRule ^/$ http://domain.com/agentur/advertising/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the following question/answer which discusses WordPress and mod_rewrite:
[.htaccess 301 redirect not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132467/htaccess-301-redirect-not-working)

In order to match against the query string, you'll need to use mod_rewrite and test against `QUERY_STRING` in a condition. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =ID=177
RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ http://blabla.com/portfolio/blablatitle/ [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^index\.asp$`) matches against the URL-path only and notably excludes the slash prefix in per-directory .htaccess files.

Note that the *CondPattern* above (ie. `=ID=177`) uses the `=` operator so is a simple string comparison (as opposed to a regex).

The more specific redirects will need to appear first, with the most general (catch-all) redirects last.

---

As mentioned in comments, to make this more general and redirect all URLs that are of the form `/index.asp?inc=index.asp&ID=NNN`, where `NNN` is any 3 digits, to a single URL then you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^inc=index\.asp&ID=\d\d\d$
RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ http://blabla.com/portfolio/blablatitle/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
So there are lots of urls like
`/index.asp?inc=index.asp&typ=Nav1&cat=2
/index.asp?inc=index.asp&typ=Nav1&cat=3`
and
`/?inc=index.asp&ID=178
/?inc=index.asp&ID=177
/?inc=index.asp&ID=176
/?inc=index.asp&ID=175
/?inc=index.asp&ID=174
/?inc=index.asp&ID=173
...`

So I have to do this for each url of the second ones? :
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} inc=index.asp&ID=173
RewriteRule ^/$ http://blabla.com/portfolio/blablatitle/ [R=301,L]

Comment: (You should add that information to your question.) Not necessarily, you can use regular expressions if there is a specific _pattern_ to these redirects. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I added the different patterns in my question. I'm still not that sure how to writte the redirects :P (Because each of them goes to a different page, like id=5 -> domain.com/portfolio-somename, id=200 -> domain.com/portfolio-someothername
If you could help me with these patterns, that would be awesome !!

Comment: If each "id" goes to a different URL and there is no obvious relationship between the source and destination URLs then you might have to do each one separately.